# .htaccess Добавить папку в адрес сайта

Tags: .htaccess

Всем привет ))
На сайте есть несколько языков. Они расположены по классике - в папках (например, /es/ ).
Не могу написать редирект на папку с языком, если в url нет языковой папки.

Например
site.ru/games/firstgame  должно перенаправляться на site.ru/es/games/firstgame
т.е. если языковой папки нет - должна подставляться "es", в других случаях оставлять без изменений.

Немного запутался в регулярнхы выражениях ))) плиз, хелп.
P.S. - сайт не мой, самописный, зачем такие бубны - не спрашивайте )))